# Regex Lookahead issue and improvement

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Right now I use below regex to skip all which is between `{% ... %}`

```
(\\|\.|\*|\/|\-|\)|\+|\$|\||\[|\]|\(|\^|\?|\!|\~|\`)(?![^{%]*?%})
```

However, that does not work properly sometimes because when i have text:

```
"This is test. ! {%.?{1}.%} .  and it doesn't work"
```

It breaks and it also matches dots in `{% %}` area which i don't want. `{` and `}` breaks it.
Negative Lookahead should look for `{%` string and not single character `{` or `}`.

All which is between `{% ... %}` should be skipped.

Any idea?

Comment: which tool are you using?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/zO9fM2/1

Comment: This is PHP language

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your regex, I saw you made some mistakes that I'm going to point.

**1-** `(?![^{%]*?%})` in simple words doesn't mean ***everything but between {%..%}***.
You used a character set `[^{%]` which means `{` **OR** `%` and not `{%` all together. So what it says is: one of those previous characters that is not **(** followed by zero or more characters except `{` OR `%` and ends to `%}` **)**

In another words you can write it like `(?!%})`, that's why those special characters are matched except that `.` before `%}`:

```
"This is test. ! {%.?{1}.%} .  and it doesn't work"
                        ^
```

**2-** So you shouldn't check for only `{` or `%` but both together. However as I see your regex you can only check for `%`: `(?![^%]*?%})`. But it will fail if in your input string is something like below:

```
"This is test.%} ! {%.%?{1}.%} .  and it doesn't work"
                     ^
```

*Pointed `dot` is captured as well.*

**3-** A good solution is using a *Tempered Dot* which I borrowed its name convention from rexegg.com: `(?!(?:(?!{%).)*?%})`

This `(?:(?!{%).)*?` is the replacement to the `[^{%]` and in inside does a negative lookahead which asserts that what follows the current position is not the string `{%`.

**4-** I don't like `(\\|\.|\*|\/|\-|\)|\+|\$|\||\[|\]|\(|\^|\?|\!|\~)` and have to replace it to something more readable and simpler: `([\/.*)($.+|^?!\[\]-])`

**5-** It doesn't guarantee correct matches for nested or unbalanced delimiters.

Final solution ([Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/nM8sQ3/1)):

```
([\/.*)($.+|^?!`\[\]-])(?!(?:(?!{%).)*?%})
```